# Is there a term to describe this type of word within a word?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a term to describe the following: a word where every other letter is capitalized and the capital letters spell another word. E.g. ToRtUrE = TRUE torture (the word "TRUE" has been capitalized within the word "torture"). It seems to be a type of kangaroo word, but I'm looking for something more specific. I'm currently using the term "interstitialism", but wondering if there is an existing term.

Comment: AnOyInG is the term I'd use.

Comment: @Hot Licks, why would you use AnOyInG... AOIG isn't a word?

Comment: @Damo - AnOyInG, isn't it?